# Homebrew on macOS: brew update says LibreSSL error: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54

Tags: ssl, curl, homebrew, macos-catalina, libressl

Since I updated to the latest version of macOS 10.15.4 Catalina, when I do `brew update` I'm getting this error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/': LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54

I used to be fine before the update (already had Catalina). Not sure what changed.

I did search around and found several topics (also older ones) regarding this problem, both here and on github. Unfortunately none of the suggestions worked for me:

- Disable ipv6
- Disable proxy (am not using one)
- Disable kaspersky or other antivirus (am not running one)
- Rebooting
- `export HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL=1` and then `brew update`
- `echo '--no-alpn' > ~/.curlrc` ; `export HOMEBREW_CURLRC=1` ; `brew update`

All to no avail, the error keeps coming up.

It doesn't mention anything curl related however from other topics on this problem I understand it's most likely related to curl. I haven't changed anything curl related myself (although maybe the latest Catalina patch did, not sure). It did work fine until a few days ago.

I also found some other suggestions that looked rather unlikely, and moreover they seemed to change some basic OS installations which I would really prefer to avoid (afraid it will lead to other incompatibilities).

**Is there an easy, safe way to fix this?**

FYI I'm using Homebrew 2.2.15.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue on my 2015 MBP after upgrading to Catalina. My work computer is a 2019 MBP, but was not encountering the same problem. Both laptops with the same version of macOS and homebrew version. The difference was that I had a lot more installed and several extra taps on my 2015 MBP.

I found and tried the same suggestions that you've tried. I even took it one step further, thinking that if I could start fresh I could solve this issue once and for all. I decided to try a fresh homebrew installation rather then the nuclear option of slicking the MBP. So I backed up the my installed list `brew list > brew.list` and `brew cask list > cask.list` and ran the uninstall [https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew]. After reinstalling homebrew I was still encountering the same problem.

I noticed that the issue was sporadic. If I ran `brew update` multiple times, with this command `seq 100 | xargs -I -- brew update`, sometimes it would succeed without the LibreSSL error. I started to look at my router. I have a Asus Wifi router with the latest firmware. I suspected that it was QOS, filter, or something TrendMicro router integration is doing.

The problem ended up being my dual wan setup. Once I forced the 2015 MBP to route through a single wan port the issue went away. The reason my work 2019 MBP wasn't encounter this issue was because I tended to be always connected to the work VPN most of the time.

I have not determined why enabling load balancing across dual wan would cause this issue since the http connection should be made and then disconnected once per request. I suspect that something is reused and not disposed of properly thus causing the SSL error.

If you don't have a dual wan setup, look in your Network settings to see if you're connected to more than one network.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, that is very unexpected. For some magical reason, `brew update` is working again and I didn't even change anything. I am however currently at a different network than the past few days. I did not at all suspect it could have anything to do with my network (my internet connection is just fine on both). But considering what you wrote, perhaps this was the reason! I'll be back at the other location in a few days and I'm gonna try again, see if the error comes back. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> Disable proxy (am not using one)

and

> started to look at my router.

Helped me figure that same problem out. Out-dated adlist on the Pi-hole was the `api.github.com`-blocking culprit in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I just quit VPN and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

For me, living in China, it may be a network problem. If you has a shadowsocks, try this to add a proxy:

```sh
$ tee ~/.gitconfig <<HERE
heredoc> [http]
        sslBackend = openssl
        proxy = socks5://127.0.0.1:1080
heredoc> HERE
```

Remember change ip and port.